# mySQL: Count unique keys across multiple tables with conditionals

Tags: mysql, duplicates, union

I have a bunch of tables ('table001', 'table002', etc) with a huge number of rows and several columns.

The columns are 'id' (the key), 'mode' (either "ui" or "cmd") and date.

I want to find out how many unique 'id's exist across all tables, whose mode is set to 'ui' and whose date is less than 30 days ago.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT id FROM table001 WHERE mode="ui" AND date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table002 WHERE mode="ui" AND date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table003 WHERE mode="ui" AND date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    UNION
    [...etc etc for 30 tables]

) as t
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: How about making a view out of your UNION and then select all unique ID from the view ?

Comment: 'Is this the correct way of doing this?' -yes it is union will dedupe ids across all tables

Answer (score 0):

If all pk ids are called `id` then you can run the stored procedure below without statically typing all tables:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE eval(IN dynamic_statement TEXT)
BEGIN
      SET @dynamic_statement := dynamic_statement;
      PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @dynamic_statement;
      EXECUTE prepared_statement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;





DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_unique_id_count_across_all_tables()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_key_fieldname VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT 'id';
    DECLARE var_tables_count INTEGER UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE var_index INTEGER UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE var_tablename_of_index VARCHAR(64);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tables_with_id;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables_with_id
    SELECT
    #     *
        (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS idx,
        TABLE_NAME AS tablename
    FROM information_schema.columns
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) A
    WHERE table_schema=SCHEMA()
    AND (COLUMN_NAME COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci) = (var_key_fieldname COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)
    ;

    SET var_tables_count := (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM tmp_tables_with_id);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_all_ids;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_all_ids(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
    );
    WHILE (var_index <= var_tables_count) DO
        SET var_tablename_of_index := (
            SELECT tablename
            FROM tmp_tables_with_id
            WHERE idx = var_index
            );
        CALL eval(CONCAT('
        INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_all_ids(id)
        SELECT
            DISTINCT t.', var_key_fieldname, '
        FROM ', var_tablename_of_index,' t
        -- ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = t.', var_key_fieldname,'
        ;
        '));
        SET var_index := var_index + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT COUNT(0) FROM tmp_all_ids;
END$$
DELIMITER;




DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS eval;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_unique_id_count_across_all_tables;


CALL sp_unique_id_count_across_all_tables();
```